# How to optimize getting multiple documents 'one by one' in Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using `Node.js` + `Firestore`. To provide more context, the structure of my database is as follows:

```
Firestore
|
|-- card (Collection)
|    |-- SCP-002 (Document)
|    |    |-- name: The "Living" Room
|    |    |-- file: http://scp-es.com/scp-002
|    |
|    |-- SCP-003 (Document)
|         |-- name: Biological Motherboard
|         |-- file: http://scp-es.com/scp-003
|
|-- obtention (Collection)
     |-- 7UHIhguG767F
     |    |-- user: /user/32138217391
     |    |-- card: /card/REG-001
     |
     |-- KkNJbVCr65TY
          |-- user: /user/08498328422
          |-- card: /card/REG-002
```

The fields in the 'obtention' documents are references to documents in the 'cards' collection. Therefore, if I want to access the data of a user's cards (such as the name) e.g for a console list, I do the following:

```
const userReference = database.collection('user').doc(interaction.user.id);

const cardsReference = database.collection('obtention').where('user', '==', userReference);
const cardsSnapshot = await cardsReference.get();

const cards = [];

for (const x of cardsSnapshot.docs) {
     const obtention = x.data();
     const cardReference = obtention.card;
     const cardDocument = await cardReference.get();

     cards.push(cardDocument);
}


// Rest of the code
```

The code works as expected, but the issue is that it takes a long time to fetch card records, and this delay increases with more data (7 seconds for about 10 records). My question is whether there's a way to speed up this process and reduce the time it takes to obtain the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an `await` for each individual `cardReference.get()` call, but gather all of these calls into an array and then pass that to `Promise.all`.

```
const promises = [];

for (const x of cardsSnapshot.docs) {
     const obtention = x.data();
     const cardReference = obtention.card;

     promises.push(cardReference.get());
}

const cards = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you! Now, fetching 30 records takes 3 seconds. However, when retrieving a larger number of documents, for example, 500, the time would be considerable. Is there a way to speed this up from Firebase, or is there a best practice for handling large amounts of data from code?

Comment: Retrieving a large number of individual documents is always going to be slow. Firestore doesn't support joins, and what you're doing is essentially a client-side version a join. The best way to speed up data retrieval is to duplicate the data, so that the data you need from each card is obtention/user document too.